# Replacing Property Value with only a get?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, properties

Quick question:

Is it possible to change the value of "MyProperty" without a setter?

```
public static void MyClass
{
    private readonly string myProperty;

    public MyClass(string property)
    {
        this.myProperty = property;
    }

    public static string MyProperty {get {return this.myProperty}}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Only once per AppDomain, via a static constructor:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string MyProperty { get; }

    static MyClass()
    {
        MyProperty = "SomeValue";
    }
}
```

Or via an initialiser:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string MyProperty { get; } = "SomeValue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a private value and use a method to set the value. If you are going to use this method, you would be better off removing the static.

```
void Main()
{
    SetValue("New Value");
}

private static string _propertyValue { get; set; }

public static string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _propertyValue;
    }
}

public static void SetValue(string value)
{
    _propertyValue = value;
}
```